# Stack and heap confusion for embedded 8051

Tags: c, memory, embedded, 8051

I am trying to understand a few basics concepts regarding the memory layout for a 8051 MCU architecture. I would be grateful if anyone could give me some clarifications.

So, for a 8051 MCU we have several types of memories:

- IRAM - (idata) - used for general purpose registers and SFRs
- PMEG - (code) - used to store code - (FLASH)
- XDATA

  - on chip (data) - cache memory for data (RAM) /
  - off-chip (xdata) - external memory (RAM)

Questions:

1. So where is the stack actually located? 
   I would assume in IRAM (idata) but it's quite small (30-7Fh)- 79 bytes
2. What does the stack do?

   Now, on one hand I read that it stores the return addresses when we call a function (e.g. when I call a function the return address is stored on the stack and the stack pointer is incremented).

   http://www.alciro.org/alciro/microcontroladores-8051_24/subrutina-subprograma_357_en.htm

   On the other hand I read that the stack stores our local variables from a function, variables which are "deleted" once we return from that function. 
   http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html
3. If I use dynamic memory allocation (heap), will that memory always be reserved in off-chip RAM (xdata), or it depends on compiler/optimization?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No, the stack is actually limited to the IRAM (most likely the upper half) as the SP is liimited to 8 bits and cannot address the XRAM. This is used to store data structures, e.g. rx/tx buffers. XRAM has been added by later derivates of the original as the IRAM is limited to 256 bytes due to 8 bit pointer registers (e.g. SP). The XRAM was added to extend this and uses an indirect addressing scheme,which is quite expensive (code/cycles) for random access.

Comment: OK; I bow to better knowledge...

Comment: I never got why the 8051 was used as much as it was, since it's so limited compared to 8080, 8085, Z8, Z80, ... ,  all of which have 16 bit stack pointers.

Comment: @rcgldr Using most of the processors you listed instead of an 8051 also would have involved higher chip counts, power consumption, cost, and complexity... 8051's were small, cheap, and adequate for what they were used for.

Comment: @rcgldr: It did include a complete microcomputer, including peripherals and RAM on a single chip and at lower costs than a CPU. Only ROM/EPROM had to be added. Back then this was mindbreaking, as the CPUs like 8080/85 required extra RAM, ROM and >2 chips for peripherals. It was also very fast with bit-operations for instance. Perfectly for control-applications. You would be surprised what you can do with this little RAM/ROM. If you have an USB-stick, it is quite likely there is an 8051-derivate inside! These chips can go up to 100MIPS, in FPGAs even more.

Comment: 8051 ... other chips.  Although it was released later, the Z8 (not Z80), was a better processor, lots of registers (128 / 256 at the time I used one), so each thread could use it's own set of registers, with on board eprom and some peripherals. I worked on an ASCII terminal that emulated a V52 using a [Zilog Z8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z8)

Comment: @rcgldr: Although?? I would say _because_ it was released later. Mostly advances in semiconductor processes (structure size!) and experience in using the older chips. HC11 and HC08 (S08) were also better - in some aspects. While I'm absolutely no fan (for its obvious disadvantages), the 8051 has also advanced very much in terms of performance as I commented. This was never achieved this degree for the Z8-family or other 8 bit MCUs. For learning it is still an adequate starter.

Comment: The main issue I have with the (original) 8051 is there's only one register to access external memory, DPTR. For 8080 / 8085 / Z80, BC, DE, or HL can be used to access external memory. For Z8, any even/odd pair of registers can be used to access external memory. It's also awkward to implement multi-threading on 8051 due to the internal stack.

Comment: I know the Z80 very good. As well as the 6502 or HC08. The latter also only had one index-register, but that still worked. The 8051 was never designed for data-processing and the XRAM was actually added later for some additional storage, as the IRAM could not be extended. In the  USB-controllers for instance the 8051 only programms DMA; it does not process the data by itself (except for header data, of course). IIRC more recent derivates have more than one index register. Similar to the PICs.

Answer (score 5):

The [8051](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) has its origin in the 1970ies/early 80ies. As such, it has very limited ressources. The original version did (for instance) not even have XRAM, that was "patched" aside later and requires special (ans slow) accesses.

The IRAM is the "main memory". It really includes the stack (yes, there are only few bytes). The rest is used for global variables ("data" and "bss" section: initialized and uninitialized globals and statics). The XRAM might be used by a compiler for the same reason.
Note that with these small MCUs you do not use many local variables (and if, only 8bit types). A clever compiler/linker (I actually used some of these) can allocate local variables statically overlapping - unless there is recursion used (very unlikely).

Most notably, programs for such systems mostly do not use a heap (i.e. dynamic memory allocation), but only statically allocated memory. At most, they might use a memory pool, which provides blocks of fixed size and does not merged blocks.

Note that the IRAM includes some special registers which can be bit-addressed by the hardware. Normally, you would use a specialized compiler which can exploit these functions. Very likely some features require special assembler functions (these might be provided in a header as C-functions just generating the corresponding machine code instruction), called intrinsics.

The different memory areas might also require compiler-extensions to be used.
You might have a look at [sdcc](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) for a suitable compiler.

Note also that the 8051 has an extended [harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) (code and data seperated with XRAM as 3rd party).

Regarding your 2nd link: This is a very generalized article; it does not cover MCUs like the 8051 (or AVR, PIC and the like), but more generalized CPUs like x86, ARM, PowerPC, MIPS, MSP430 (which is also a smaller MCU), etc. using an **external** [von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) (internally most (if not all) 32+ bitters use a harvard architecture).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have direct experience with your chips, but I have worked with very constrained systems in the past.  So here is what I can answer:

Question 1 and 2: The stack is more than likely set within a very early startup routine.  This will set a register to tell it where the stack should start.  Typically, you want this in memory that is very fast to access because compiled code loves pushing and popping memory from the stack all the time.  This includes return addresses in calls, local variable declarations, and the occasional call to directly allocate stack memory (alloca).

For your 3rd question, the heap is set wherever your startup routine set it to.
There is no particular area that a heap needs to live.  If you want it to live in external memory, then it can be set there.  You want it in your really small/fast area, you can do that too, though that is probably a very bad idea.  Again, your chip's/compiler's manual or included code should show you an overloaded call to malloc().  From here, you should be able to walk backwards to see what addresses are being passed into its memory routines.

Your IRAM is so dang small that it feels more like Instruction RAM - RAM where you would put a subroutine or two to make running code from them more efficient.  80 bytes of stack space will evaporate very quickly in a typical C function call framework.  Actually, for sizes like this, you might have to hand assemble stuff to get the most out of things, but that may be beyond your scope.

If you have other questions, let me know.  This is the kind of stuff I like doing :)

---

Update

[This page](http://what-when-how.com/8051-microcontroller/8051-register-banks-and-stack/) has a bunch of good information on stack management for your particular chip.  It appears that the stack for this chip is indeed in IRAM and is very very constrained.  It also appears that assembly level coding on this chip would be the norm as this amount of RAM is quite small indeed.

Heck, this is the first system I've seen in many years that has bank switching as a way to access more RAM.  I haven't done that since the Color Gameboy's Z80 chip.

Comment: Try the PIC controllers. AVRs are also very restricted, much like S05/08 MCUs. The 6502 had also some limitations as much as the HC11. The systems you worked with might have been not _that_ restricted as you thought;-). However, believe it or not, you can get along with C pretty well if you know the limitations (e.g. use only `(u)int8_t`, etc..

Comment: Back in my day... Get off my lawn!  Lol.  My first experience with embedded fun was the original Gaeboy.  8k RAM, 4k paged, no shadow registers, no ix/iy registers because it was emulated on a different chip, etc.  The C compiliers were so poor at the time we had to code straight assembly just to make the games perform.  Fun times :)

Comment: Pffft! Young fella *cough*. Gameboy. That was a piece of paper and a TTL-handbook with a self-made breadboard (well, kinda). My first computer (self-made, own design) had a 6502 with 2KiB RAM (brand-new CMOS chip). Programmed bitwise using some self-made EPROM-emulator with the same RAM. I would have sold an arm for a C-compiler (not that I had known what C or a compiler was). Ok, 6pm, gotta go to bed; nurse 's waiting ... *cough*. Man, I fell old - thank you ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the heap:

There is also a malloc/free couple

You have to call init_mempool(), which is indicated in compiler documentation but it is somewhat uncommon.

The pseudo-code below to illustrate this.

However I used it only this way and did not try heavy used of malloc/free like you may find in dynamic linked list management, so I have no idea of the performance you get out of this.

```
//A "large" place in xdata to be used as heap
static char xdata heap_mem_pool [1000];

//A pointer located in data and pointing to something in xdata
//The size of the pointer is then 2 bytes instead of 3 ( the 3rd byte 
//store the area specification data, idata, xdata )
//specifier not mandatory but welcome
char xdata * data shared_memory;

//...

u16 mem_size_needed;

init_mempool (heap_mem_pool, sizeof(heap_mem_pool));

//..

mem_size_needed = calcute_needed_memory();

shared_memory  =  malloc(mem_size_needed); 
if ( 0 == shared_memory   ) return -1;

//...use shared_memory pointer

//free if not needed anymore
free(shared_memory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some **additionnal consequences** about the fact that **in general no function is reentrant** ( or with some effort ) due to this *stackless* microcontroller.

I will call "my system" the systemI am working on at the present time: C8051F040 (Silab) with Keil C51 compiler ( I have no specific interest in these 2 companies )

The (function return address) stack is located low in the iram (idata on my system).

If it start at 30(dec) it means you have  either global or local variables in your code that you requested to be in data RAM ( either because you choose a "*small*" memory model or because you use the keyword *data* in the variable declaration ).

Whenever *you call a function the return 2 bytes address of the caller function will be save in this stack ( 16 bits code space )* **and that's all**: no registers saving, no arguments pushed onto the **(non-existing)(data)** stack. Your compiler may also limit the functions call depth.

Necessary arguments and local variables ( and certainly saved registers ) are placed somewhere in the RAM ( data RAM or XRAM )

So now imagine that you want to use the same innocent function ( like memcpy() ) both in your interrupt and in you normal infinite loop, it will cause sporadic bugs. Why ?

Due to the lack of stack, **the compiler must share RAM memory places for arguments, local variables ...**  between several functions **THAT DO NOT BELONG to the same call tree branch**

The pitfall is that an interrupt is its own call tree.

So if an interrupt occurs while you were executing e.g the memcpy() in your "normal task", you may **corrupt** the execution of memcpy() because when going out of the interrupt execution, the pointers dedicated to the copy performed in the normal task will have the (end) value of the copy performed in the interrupt.

On my system I get a *L15 linker error* when the compiler detects that a function is called by more than one independant "branch"

You may make a function reentrant with the addition of the **reentrant** keyword **and** requiring the creation of an *emulated stack* on the top of the XRAM for example. I did not test on my system because I am already lacking of XRAM memory which is only 4kB.

See link
[C51: USING NON-REENTRANT FUNCTION IN MAIN AND INTERRUPTS](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2042.htm)

Comment: Note that the C51 compiler is now free on my system: you must retrieve a serial number when registering at Silabs and you use this number to get your free license by Keil.

Comment: [A book with some good information](http://www.silabs.com/Marcom%20Documents/Resources/embedded-programming-textbook.zip)

Answer (score 0):

In the standard 8051 uC, the stack occupies the same address space as register bank 1(08H to 0FH) by default at start up. That means, the stack pointer(SP register) will be having a value of 07H at startup(incremented to 08H when stack is PUSHed). This probably limits the stack memory to 8 bytes, if register bank 2(starting from 10H) is occuppied. If register banks 2 and 3 are not used, even that can be taken up by the stack(08H to 1FH).

If in a given program we need more than 24 bytes (08 to 1FH = 24 bytes) of stack, we can change the SP to point to RAM locations 30 – 7FH. This is done with the instruction “MOV SP, #xx”. This should clarify doubts surrounding the 8051 stack usage.